# If $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent for $x$ then $||x_n||$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, weak-convergence

We make use of the following dual formula for the norm of every $x \in X$:

**Lemma**: Let $(X,||\cdot||)$. Then $||x|| = \sup_{\substack{f \in X^*\\||f|| \neq 0}}\frac{|f(x)|}{||f||}$ for every $x \in X$.

**Proof of the main result**: Since $x_n \overset{w}{\rightarrow} x$, then for every functional $f \in X^*$ we have $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) = f(x).$$Since $(f(x_n))$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers it is bounded, say $|f(x)| \leq K_f$ for each functional $f$. Since we have convergence in every functional then taking the supremum on both sides over each $f$ we must get a finite amount for $K_f$, otherwise there would be a contradiction with the weakly convergence of $(x_n)$. But then, according with the lemma, $$||x_n|| = \sup_{\substack{f \in X^*\\||f|| \neq 0}}\frac{|f(x_n)|}{||f||} \leq \frac{K_f}{||f||}.$$It remains to show the result for the case $||f|| = 0$.

**Question**: Can anyone provide an hint on how to complete the proof? I can't find a way to relate the zero functional with the sequence $(x_n)$.

**Remark:** Notice that the proof could make use of the powerful theorem of Banach-Steinhaus; however I am trying to show it without making use of such tool.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there is a gap where you say "taking the supremum on both sides over each $f$ we must get a finite amount for $K_f$."  Since you are taking the supremum over infinitely many $f$, I don't see why that would have to give a finite value.

Comment: @user6247850 If it wasn't for, say $f'$, then wouldn't it imply the divergence of $(f'(x_n))$? So that it wouldn't converge for $f(x)$?

Comment: You're assuming there exists some $f'$ that achieves the supremum, but that isn't doesn't need to be the case.  For example, what if there exists some $f_n$ such that $K_{f_n} = n$?  Each $f_n$ is still bounded, but $\sup K_{f_n} = \infty$.

Comment: @user6247850 I don't understand why that would be the case? Since $K$ is simply the upper bound for each $f$. And we're sure that each upper bound is finite

Comment: But there are infinitely many $K$.  You understand that $n < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, right?  And that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n = \infty$ even though each $n$ is finite?  The supremum of infinitely many finite numbers can be infinite.